# Set form specific property as valid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have form and i want to set one of its property to valid based on some condition.

Lets say,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="Registration">
  <form name="studentRegisteration">
     <input type="number" id="input" name="input" model="input">
  </form>
</form>
```

I am trying as following but i see in immediate window (Visual studio), it gives undefined outcome.

```
$scope.Registration.studentRegisteration.input.$setValidity('integer', false);
```

`'integer'` is a property i am setting it false in my directive.

I want to do this so eventually form becomes valid.

I am not sure i am doing in right away using my above statement.
Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access a nested form you need to first use `form` then `ng-form`.

I modified your code a bit in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KRqP2oVWvc5hSOfMgD9V?p=info) to show you.